# Split by separator into many columns

Tags: r

How is it possible from a dataframe which contains one column which contains values separated by ";"

```
df  <-data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), stock = c("Google;Yahoo","Microsoft;Google","Yahoo"))
```

produce a dataframe like this:

```
df  <-data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), stock_1 = c("Google","Microsoft","Yahoo"), stock_2 = c("Yahoo","Google","NA"))
```

Comment: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(df, "stock", ";")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) separate_rows**  Use `separate_rows` to convert it to long form, add a `name` column containing the eventual column names and use `spread` to convert it back to wide form.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
   separate_rows(stock) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(name = paste("stock", seq_along(stock), sep = "_")) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   spread(name, stock)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id   stock_1 stock_2
* <dbl>     <chr>   <chr>
1     1    Google   Yahoo
2     2 Microsoft  Google
3     3     Yahoo    <NA>
```

**2) separate** If we knew that there were no more than 2 sub-fields then we could use `separate` giving the same.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
   separate(stock, c("stock_1", "stock_2"), fill = "right")
```

**3) read.table** This approach uses no packages.

```
stocks <- read.table(text = as.character(df$stock), sep = ";", as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
names(stocks) <- paste("stock", seq_along(stocks), sep = "_")
cbind(df[1], stocks)
```

giving:

```
  id   stock_1 stock_2
1  1    Google   Yahoo
2  2 Microsoft  Google
3  3     Yahoo
```

Answer (score 2):

Comment to answer, plus another option for completeness:

## splitstackshape

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "stock", ";")
#    id   stock_1 stock_2
# 1:  1    Google   Yahoo
# 2:  2 Microsoft  Google
# 3:  3     Yahoo      NA
```

## data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("stock_1", "stock_2") := tstrsplit(stock, ";")][, stock := NULL][]
#    id   stock_1 stock_2
# 1:  1    Google   Yahoo
# 2:  2 Microsoft  Google
# 3:  3     Yahoo      NA
```